# Need help! Converting .asp code to .php

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm working on a site that was was .asp and I'm converting it to PHP and one of the forms has this little bit of code in it...

```
response.write("<script language=javascript>")&vbnewline&vbnewline
response.write("var code = " &vInput& " ^ 2153893326;")&vbnewline&vbnewline
response.write("</script>")&vbnewline&vbnewline
```

The only part of this I don't understand is "^ 2153893326".

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated: It's wrapped in JS.

Comment: That's not code, it's text...

Comment: That code is writing a JS statement, the `^` is a [Bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: I figured it out. It's JS bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 0):

**^ (Bitwise XOR)**
Performs the XOR operation on each pair of bits. a XOR b yields 1 if a and b are different. The truth table for the XOR operation is: